# Retrievin a class from an html in electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I have a basic electron app where I am trying to retrieve data from the the html's document form. I basically want ot retrive data like in a ordinary html document with something like `const form =
document.querySelector('form');` but when I start the program it always shows an error that document is not defined

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});

mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'MainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));

const form = document.querySelector('form');
});
```

---

```
<body>
    <main>
        <form class="submit-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Text..">
            <button>Search</button>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is available only in *Renderer* process. So you have to call your query there.
Most straightforward thing to do in your case is to [`executeJavaScript`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) on `BrowserWindow`'s `webContents`

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
  mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    // manipulate form...
  `)
})
```